# Backspace won't function correctly with StringBuilder in C# console

Tags: c#, string, console-application, keyboard-events, backspace

I am trying to create a screen where the user would be able to write down their name with StringBuilder.

The problems I have is with the functionality of backspace. I can remove all letters except the first letter that was pressed. Also, it seems like I can press whatever character and it would be submitted.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
bool enterPressed = false;
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
int temp = 61;
do
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(temp, 14);
    cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && name.Length > 0 && name.Length < 12)
    {
        enterPressed = true;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(61, 18);
        Console.Write(name);
    }
    else if ("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".Contains(cki.KeyChar) && name.Length < 12)
    {
         name.Append(cki.KeyChar);
         Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);
         temp += 1;
    }
    else if(cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && name.Length > 0)
    {
         name.Remove(name.Length-1, 1);
         Console.Write("\b \b");
    }
} while (name.Length > 0 && !enterPressed);
```

Comment: Are you aware of Console.ReadLine()? that already does what you want I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to do `temp--;`
This code snippet should solve your problem

```
                name.Remove(name.Length - 1, 1);
                temp--;
                Console.Write("\b \b");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
  console.Writeline("Enter Your Name");
  string name= console.Readline();
```

and below is something for you to update if you don't want to use above solution.

```
if(cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && name.Length >= 0)
{
    if (name.Length == 0)
    {
        name.Remove(0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        name.Remove(name.Length - 1, 1);
    }
     temp--;
    Console.Write(" ");   
}
```